# bash - How to assign the results to 0 or 1?

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2

I wanna assign the json results if it get successful is 0 and failed is 1.

The results is success as below:

```
[root@jenkins qemu-server]# aws elb describe-instance-health --profile test --load-balancer-name classic-balance-test
{
    "InstanceStates": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-05414ddade7f312ff",
            "ReasonCode": "Instance",
            "State": "OutOfService",
            "Description": "Instance is in stopped state."
        },
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-0ccf638d2cd59bc73",
            "ReasonCode": "Instance",
            "State": "OutOfService",
            "Description": "Instance is in stopped state."
        }
    ]
}
```

The results is failed as below:

```
[root@jenkins qemu-server]# aws elb describe-instance-health --profile test --load-balancer-name classic-balance-test1

An error occurred (LoadBalancerNotFound) when calling the DescribeInstanceHealth operation: There is no ACTIVE Load Balancer named 'classic-balance-test1'
```

Comment: To what do you want to assign the result ? I'm pretty sure you can do what you want by using `$?`

Comment: What does `echo "The status is $?"` print if executed immediately after `aws` in the two cases?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try running `echo $?` which will print out the status code of the last thing executed.

So you could assign a variable to that command like so `results=$(echo $?)`

and when you `echo $results` you'll get the status code of the command ran

From the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html):

> These are the following return codes returned at the end of execution
>   of a CLI command:
>
> 0 -- Command was successful. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> To determine the return code of a command, run the following right
>   after running a CLI command. Note that this will work only on POSIX
>   systems:
>
> ```
> $ echo $?
> ```

Comment: maybe you should add something like `result=$?; echo $result`, so that your answer also covers the "assign" in the question